# search method for a char in a list of chars in java

Tags: java, list, search, recursion, char

I'm looking to search through a list of added chars and return a "Yes" or "no" answer to whether a certain character appears in my given list.  I'm new to this and not too sure where to start - any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

```
class Csc2001Node
{
protected char ch;
protected Csc2001Node next;

/*
* Construct a Csc2001Node with the given character value 
* @param c - The character 
*/
public Csc2001Node (char c)
{
    this.ch = c;
    this.next = null;
}
}   

public class Csc2001LinkedListRec
{  /* A reference to the head of the list */
protected Csc2001Node head;
/*
* Construct a new empty list 
*/
public Csc2001LinkedListRec()
{
    head=null;
}

public Csc2001Node getHead()
{
    return head;
}


 /*
 * Finds the size of a list.
 * @param head The head of the current list
 * @return The Size of the Current List
 */
 private int size(Csc2001Node head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + size(head.next);
    }
 }

 /*
 * Wrapper method for finding the size of a list.
 * @return The size of the list
 */
 public int size() {
    return size(head);
 }


 /*
 * Adds a new node to the end of a list.
 * @param head The head of the current list
 * @param c The character for the new node
 */
 private void add(Csc2001Node head, char c) {
    // If the list has just one character, add to it.
    if (head.next == null) {
        head.next = new Csc2001Node(c);
    } else {
        add(head.next, c); // Add to rest of list.
    }
 }

 /*
 * Wrapper method for adding a new node to the end of a list.
 * @param c The character for the new node
 */
 public void add(char c) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Csc2001Node(c); // List has 1 node.
    } else {
        add(head, c);
    }
 }


 /*
 *Test to see if this list is empty 
 *@returns true or false
 */ 
 public boolean isEmpty()
 {
    return (head == null);
 }


 /*
 * Replaces all occurrences of oldch with newch.
 * @post Each occurrence of oldch has been replaced by newch.
 * @param head The head of the current list
 * @param oldch The character being removed
 * @param newch The character being inserted
 */
 private void replace(Csc2001Node head, char oldch, char newch) {
    if (head != null) {
        if (oldch == head.ch) {
            head.ch = newch;
        }
        replace(head.next, oldch, newch);
    }
 }

 /*
 Wrapper method for replacing oldch with newch.
 * @post Each occurrence of oldch has been replaced by newch.
 * @param oldch The character being removed
 * @param newch The character being inserted
 */
 public void replace(char oldch, char newch) {
    replace(head, oldch, newch);
 }




 //added methods


 //method to recursively print the characters
 private String  recursePrintList(Csc2001Node head) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (head == null)
    return "List is empty";
 else
    while(head.next!=null){
        return head.ch+ recursePrintList(head.next);
    }
 return head.ch + " ";
 }

 /*
 * Wrapper to print out list
 *@return the list
 */

 public void recursePrintList(){
    System.out.println(recursePrintList(head));
 }




 //method to insert char d before char c
 private Csc2001Node insertBefore(char d, Csc2001Node head, char c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     {   
            if(head==null){
                return head = new Csc2001Node(d);
            }                       
             else if(head.next.ch == c){
                 head = head.next;
                 head.next = new Csc2001Node(d);
                 head.next.next = head;
             }

        }
    return head;    

}

/*Wrapper method for inserting a char before another char
 * 
 */
public void insertBefore(char c, char d){
    head = insertBefore(c, head, d);
}

 public boolean search(char c) {


    return false;
 }


}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @amit The question is: could you guys do my homework? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
public boolean search(char c) {
    return search(head, c);
}


private boolean search(Csc2001Node node, char c) {
    if (node == null)
        return false;
    else if (node.ch == c)
        return true;
    else
        return search(node.next, c); 
}
```

More elegant but less readable:

```
public boolean search(char c) {
    return search(head, c);
}


private boolean search(Csc2001Node node, char c) {
    return node != null && (node.ch == c || search(node.next, c));
}
```

Of course, you can use a loop for the non-recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to see if a certain character is in the list with the `search()` method? If that's the case, you need to traverse through the entire list with a loop. Check to see if the current value matches the character that was passed to the method. If you reach the end of the list, return false. It should look something like this:

```
public boolean search(char c) {
    Csc2001Node current = head;
    while (current is not at the end of the list) {
        if (current.character equals c) {
            return true;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
search(entry, ch)
    if entry == null
        return false
    if entry.ch == ch
        return true
    return search(entry.next, ch)
```

...would be a recursive solution. And something like:

```
search(entry, ch)
    while entry != null
        if entry.ch == ch
            return true
        entry = entry.next
    return false
```

...would be an iterative solution. I'm not giving you Java code, only pseudocode, because this looks like a homework assignment.